# dynamic display of a running process?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting, text-user-interface

I am writing a script and according to that when I run it certain info will be displayed on the output screen.

for example say the **constant data** displayed is:

```
my name is mukesh.
i am 27 years old
unix version 7.2.3.0
```

but along with the above display something else is also need to be displayed(**varying data**) I.e

```
Process A is starting
Process A is running
Process A is completed.
```

but I don't want the above display.

I want `Process A is starting` to be cleared from screen
and replaced by `Process A is running` and then by `Process A is completed.`

I am not very keen to use `clear` as it will remove the whole screen containing the **constant data** also.
and also because the constant data takes a lot of time to process and to be displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clear a line and use carriage return (`\r`) to get to the beginning of the line.

```
clr2eol=`tput el`                              # capture escape sequence for "clear-to-end-of-line"
echo -n "Process A has started."               # display without a newline
sleep 3
echo -n "\r${clr2eol}Process A is running."    # move to beginning of line (bol), clear, and display new text
sleep 5
echo -n "\r${clr2eol}Process A has completed." # again, move to bol, clear and display new test
echo                                           # terminating newline  you may not want to have this sent right away
```

Read the manpage on [`terminfo`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?terminfo+5).

Answer (score 3):

The carriage return character (`\r`) will return to the beginning of the current line, so you can overwrite text:

```
printf "%s\r" "Process A is starting  "
sleep 5
printf "%s\r" "Process A is running   "
sleep 5
printf "%s\n" "Process A is completed."
```

Answer (score 0):

To do something like that you'll have to use some like (n)curses: http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/

Comment: i need to look into  this ...new for me thanks again

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).