# How does many binaries changes the percent number of the execution in its right place?

Tags: terminal, c, text, programming

I'm trying to write a C program which can do the thing that many binaries such as `package managers` do in execution time. They change and add to the already outputted texts in terminal and it makes it fun. I want to know how can I do this, not only in C, maybe in bash or python. For example:

```
 program                  23 MiB   981 KiB/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
```

I mean a thing like this, the `#` grows up in downloading process.

Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Related: [dynamic display of a running process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33868/dynamic-display-of-a-running-process)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is typically done by printing the complete line over and over again, using a carriage return instead of a line feed to return the cursor to the start of the line instead of the next. For example,

```bash
for i in {0..20}; do
  printf "ETA %2.1ds [%-20.${i}s]\r" "$((20-i))" "####################"
  sleep 1
done
printf "\n"
```

Carriage return is represented by `\r` in many C-inspired contexts.

More complex displays are typically constructed using a [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library))-style library. This is how many full-screen “text-mode” applications handle their output; see for example [Midnight Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander).

Comment: One issue with this method is that the terminal helpfully forgets the overwritten text. But if you redirect the output to a file, it will appear to be one long line because \r is not a line terminator. Linux is relatively benign with long lines, but some older *nix commands used to have maximum line lengths. `[[ -t 1 ]]` can be helpful.